# How to get geo coordinates on emulator WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is it possible? I mean on 7.1 version, not 7.0 with [GPSEmulator](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/GPS-Emulator)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something here - why not use the additional tools* that come with the emulator to spoof a location?

*mouse over the emulator, and click on the "»" symbol to show the additional tools.